# Syntax Error on makeExecutableSchema: Unexpected Name "User" (GraphQL)

Tags: node.js, graphql

I need some help to solve an error on graphql, I can't find anything on this case.

I tried to separate my different schemas and resolvers to make it easier to maintain, but when I use makeExecutableSchema function (from graphql-tools package), a "GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "User"" error is throw.

So here is the Error :

```
/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:153
  throw unexpected(lexer);
  ^
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "User"
    at syntaxError (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:24:10)
    at unexpected (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1490:33)
    at parseDefinition (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:153:9)
    at many (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1523:16)
    at parseDocument (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:113:18)
    at Object.parse (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:48:10)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:19:33)
    at makeExecutableSchema (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasblanquet/EIP_Routs/API/routs-api/graphql/schema.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! routs-api@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the routs-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And here is my code :

For the User schema :

```
const User = `
User {
  _id: Int!
  username: String!
  email: String!
}

extend type Query {
    users: [User]
}
`;

module.exports = User;
```

For the resolver (the model is create with sequelize and I'm using Apollo-Server-Express):

```
const User = require('../../server/models/user')
const Messages = require('../messages');

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users(parent, args, context, info) {
      parent.getUsers()
    },
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

And finally the code to put the schemas and resolvers together :

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const resolvers = require('./resolver');
const User = require('./user/schema');

const Query =
`type Query {
  _empty: String
}`;

const Mutation =
`type Mutation {
  _empty: String
}`;

module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [Query, Mutation, User],
  resolvers,
});
```

I really can't find anything about this kind of problem, thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing that error because you left off the `type` keyword in your User type definition. It should be:

```
type User {
  _id: Int!
  username: String!
  email: String!
}
```

Also be mindful that your resolver is calling `getUsers` on the root object, which will also probably blow up (I imagine you meant to use your model instead).

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right about the `getUsers` too !